# How do I place my menu on the right side of my website?

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery website and I'm trying to make a menu on the right of the screen, however the menu items are on the bottom of the images, rather to the right of them. Regardless of where I set the width in classes gallerymenu, and menutyle, the menu items still remain below the images. How would I accomplish what I  want to do?

```
<body class="galleryStyle">
    <div class="galleryGrid"> 
      <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div>
          <a href="google.com.html">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/23/Philipgiaccone1.JPG" alt="google">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div>
          <a href="google.com.html">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Delfini-Milian_cropped.png" alt="google">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
<div class="galleryMenu">
    <div class="menuStyle">
      <a href="google.com">
        <p>google</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuStyle">
      <a href="google.com">
        <p>google</p></a>
    </div>

.galleryStyle {
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.galleryContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.galleryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 8fr);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
}

.galleryMenu  {
  height: 30%;
}

.menuContainer>div {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 8px 13px black;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
}

.menuStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ud3rfm2o/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your code is to use float:left on the pictures and float:right on the menu.  also give width to menu lt 40% and margin-top 40px to align tops.

That said, flexbox is generally easier to work with.

```css
.galleryStyle {
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.galleryContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.galleryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 8fr);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  float:left;
}

.galleryMenu  {
  height: 30%;
}

.menuContainer>div {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 8px 13px black;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 40%;
}

.menuStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
  width:25%;
  float:right;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<body class="galleryStyle">
    <div class="galleryGrid"> 
      <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div>
          <a href="google.com.html">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/23/Philipgiaccone1.JPG" alt="google">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div>
          <a href="google.com.html">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Delfini-Milian_cropped.png" alt="google">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
<div class="galleryMenu">
    <div class="menuStyle">
      <a href="google.com">
        <p>google</p></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuStyle">
      <a href="google.com">
        <p>google</p></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what happens but when I add it to my website they still go to the bottom. I added each image one by one, but once I got to the 4th image the menu went to the bottom. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Actually nevermind it somehow works now... Although how would I make the menu item boxes bigger (vertically)? Which class would I adjust?

Comment: Lastly, why doesn't the box shadow appear on the menu items anymore?

Comment: you are missing a closing div tag

Answer (score 0):

try `float: right;` on `galleryMenu`:

```
.galleryMenu  {
  height: 30%;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: If I do that the menu is still below the images, try it on the fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

use flex:

```
    <body class="galleryStyle">
    <div class= gallery-wrap>


        <div class="galleryGrid"> 
          <div class="galleryContainer">
            <div>
              <a href="google.com.html">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/23/Philipgiaccone1.JPG" alt="google">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="galleryContainer">
            <div>
              <a href="google.com.html">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Delfini-Milian_cropped.png" alt="google">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    <div class="galleryMenu">
        <div class="menuStyle">
          <a href="google.com">
            <p>google</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="menuStyle">
          <a href="google.com">
            <p>google</p></a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```
.gallery-wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
   justify-content:space-between;

}
.galleryStyle {
  color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.galleryContainer {
  height: auto;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.galleryGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 8fr);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
}

.galleryMenu  {
  height: 30%;
  flex-grow:1
}

.menuContainer>div {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 8px 13px black;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50%;
  width: 20%;
}

.menuStyle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

for a full guide on flex:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: where do I apply the gallery wrap class? In your updated code you didn't add it to the html part.

Comment: oh, it should wrap the elements you want to wrap, look edited code